# How to pause and resume 'socketserver'?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, serversocket, socketserver

How do we **pause and resume** 'socketserver'???

I've been looking at socketserver documentation but I couldn't find the reference. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html.

- I initialize my socketserver

  ```
  server = socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler)
  server_thread = Thread(target=server.serve_forever, args=())
  server_thread.daemon = False
  server_thread.start()
  ```
- After, we get the input "offline 5" which means socketserver pauses offline for 5 seconds and comeback

  ```
  if text.split()[0] == 'offline':
      duration = text.split()[1]

      server.pause() ## ??????? PAUSE
      print('Sleeping')
      time.sleep(int(duration))

      server.resume() ## ???????? RESUME
      print('Node got up')
  ```